# View questions no answer has been selected

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, accepted-answer

I think the user profile page should have an additional filter tab/button added to the current filters of: `recent` `votes` `newest` `views` that `Unanswered` or similar should be added.

This would make easier for users to review which questions they have not accepted an answer on. Having to manually page through all of your questions to find which do not have an answer marked as accepted is painstaking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the [Advanced Super Ninja Search Options](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=), you can accomplish this by using the following query:

```
user:me hasaccepted:0
```

[Here's yours!](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame+hasaccepted%3A0)

It isn't on the user page, but it is possible to find those questions.

Comment: Clearly this just needs added as a tab button to the profile page then.