# Unaccepted tab in question list

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, tabs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [View questions no answer has been selected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84659/view-questions-no-answer-has-been-selected)

I've posted 74 questions in total and I recently noticed that my accept rate was 99%. Since I always pay attention to accept answers if they solved my problem and I didn't remembered of any question unanswered I've take a look at my question list.

I noticed there is no 'Unaccepted' tab on the question list that would be useful to easily find questions you did not appropriately closed by accepting an answer.

The reasons to implement it are few and too lazy-style to be listed here. At the same time I think it's not really hard to accomplish this request and adding just a tab to make me (or someone else) happy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see your questions which are not accepted using the search box:

[user:me hasaccepted:0](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:me%20hasaccepted:0)

On one hand, I don't think that this requires a tab.  On the other hand we do want to encourage users to accept answers, and this is a reasonable hint for them.

Comment: How many users do know `user:me hasaccepted:0`? I didn't for example.

Comment: @Charlie Judging by how often we get different versions of this request (on the profile page, for example), the number of knowledgeable users just increases. ♪

Comment: @Charlie The search options can be found simply by doing an empty search in the search box.  There's a lot there to discover, but it's not promoted generally.  People find out when they visit meta trying to figure out how to make their lives easier, such as you've done.

Comment: @SachinShanbhag and @CharliePigarelli I just added it to the faq:  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/86274/how-do-i-see-which-of-my-questions-are-not-accepted

Comment: @Will - Thank you. Saw that just now. ;)

Comment: @SachinShanbhag: NP.  Since I had no clue either, I figured I'd leave it where I could find it when I forget about this again.

Answer (score 0):

If you have accepted an answer the number of answers is in yellow, otherwise it is in white, so they are visually different (unless you're colour blind). It may be difficult to go through all your questions though.