# How do I see which of my questions are not accepted?

Tags: support, faq, questions, answers, accepted-answer

I want to quickly see all questions I have asked where I have not [accepted an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234). How do I do this?

[Return to FAQ index](/q/7931/)

Answer (score 24):

You can find questions you have asked but have no accepted answer by searching for:

[user:me hasaccepted:0](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84659/view-questions-no-answer-has-been-selected/84663#84663)

The above link points to Stack Overflow, but the search can be performed on any Stack Exchange site.

<sub>Answer taken from [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84659/view-questions-no-answer-has-been-selected/84663#84663).</sub>